# Criando um Quiz em Django e Javascript

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, for

Estou fazendo um quiz em Django e usando Javascript também. Porém, quero que cada pergunta crie um dicionário contendo a questão, opções e a opção correta. 
Estava fazendo dessa forma:

```js
const myQuestions = [
    {
      question: "{{ quiz.0.1 }}",
      answers: {
        "a": "{{ quiz.0.2 }}",
        "b": "{{ quiz.0.3 }}",
        "c": "{{ quiz.0.4 }}",
        "d": "{{ quiz.0.5 }}"
      },
      correctAnswer: "{{ quiz.0.6 }}"
    },
    {
      question: "{{ quiz.1.1 }}",
      answers: {
        "a": "{{ quiz.1.2 }}",
        "b": "{{ quiz.1.3 }}",
        "c": "{{ quiz.1.4 }}",
        "d": "{{ quiz.1.5 }}"
      },
      correctAnswer: "{{ quiz.1.6 }}"
    }
```

Só que dessa forma seria manual, e queria, usando um **for** para deixar ele mais automático.  Porém,  estou com problemas ao tentar fazer:

```js
const myQuestions = [      
    {% for item in quiz %}
      {
        question: "{{ item.question }}",
        answers: {
          "a": "{{ item.option1 }}",
          "b": "{{ item.option2 }}",
          "c": "{{ item.option3 }}",
          "d": "{{ item.option4 }}"
        },
        correctAnswer: "{{ item.answer }}"
      }      
    {% endfor %}

  ];
```

Essa é a parte que pega as perguntas, opções e resposta:

````js
myQuestions.forEach(
      (currentQuestion, questionNumber) => {

        // variable to store the list of possible answers
        const answers = [];

        // and for each available answer...
        for(letter in currentQuestion.answers){

          // ...add an HTML radio button
          answers.push(
            `<label class="text-sans-serif text-dark radio">
              <input type="radio" name="question${questionNumber}" value="${letter}" required>
              <span>${currentQuestion.answers[letter]}</span> 
            </label>`
          );
        }

        // add this question and its answers to the output
        output.push(
          `<div class="slide">
            <div class="question mt-0 text-center"> ${currentQuestion.question} </div>
            <div class="answers"> ${answers.join("")} </div>
          </div>`
        );
      }
    );
    ```

Simplesmente ele não aparece nada.
````

Comment: Caso queiram, mando o código todo.

Comment: Oi, são sempre 6?

Comment: É a questão, as 4 opções e a resposta.

Comment: Porém existem muitas perguntas, por isso gostaria do FOR

Comment: Acho que só te falta a virgula no fim do objeto, antes de `{% endfor %}`. Se não for isso podes colocar aqui o resultado desse for quando chega ao browser?

Comment: Ele não retorna nada. Fica em branco.

Comment: [Print do Resultado] (https://i.imgur.com/0FJBuiJ.png) 
OBS: Esses botões não eram para aparecer, somente o "Próxima Questão".

Comment: Podes mostrar código HTML (Javascript no caso deste loop) em vez dessa imagem? e tens algum erro na consola?

Comment: Não aparece nenhum erro. O código Javascript inteiro está aqui: https://ghostbin.co/paste/rwasb

Comment: Nesse link ainda estão partes do Django... `{% for item in quiz %}`. Isso vai renderizar num ficheiro certo?

Comment: ```py
@login_required
def conhecimento_geral(request):
 return render(request, "quiz1.html", {"quiz": Quizzes.objects.get_queryset().all()})
```

Comment: Queria pegar os valores e ir criando dicts a cada pergunta automaticamente. O Javascript vai fazer um forEach e pegar cada valor, entende? Só que o problema está na parte do for do Django.

Comment: Eu percebo, desde o inicio... esse Django tem um loop para gerar objetos Javascript certo?

Comment: O Django (Quiz) retorna todas as perguntas, opções e respostas. O loop seria pra criar os dicionários com cada pergunta.

Comment: O problema está ai

Comment: Consegui resolver, muito obrigado mesmo assim.